# Children of a flexbox don't take up all the width of the container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

#right {
  background: purple;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="left">left</div>
  <div id="right">right</div>
</div>
```

From my understanding, if a width is not specified for the flexbox children, they should each take equal amounts of space to fill the parent. So from this, I thought that both `#left` and `#right` would take up 50% of `#parent` in width, but instead they seem to just take up the amount of space they need.

Why are they not `50%` of the parent each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You additionally need to tell the children that they're allowed to expand to fill the available space, by applying **[`flex-grow: 1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)** to both of the children. Also note that flex children automatically take up the full height of the parent, so you don't need `height: 100%` on the children:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  background: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#right {
  background: purple;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="left">left</div>
  <div id="right">right</div>
</div>
```